# NullPointerException Question on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, canonical

I saw a moderator closed one question in which OP had issue related to `NullPointerException`

- [How can I make this custom adapter work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685876/how-can-i-make-this-custom-adapter-work)

I don't know whether it is right to do so or not.

We all know there are already many existing questions which are related to `NullPointerException` and many new questions which refer "only" to the concept of `NullPointerException` are being posted everyday.

So should we close them as duplicates of this:
[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

See Example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686048/getsherlockactivity-getintent-getstringextra-prints-then-throws-nullpoint#comment36392781_23686274
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682474/how-can-i-add-images-from-mainactivity-so-pager-adapter-can-read-it
  etc.

Comment: Was it a trigger-happy closure?  The first question was tagged for 'Andriod' and the 'reference' question was tagged for 'Java'.  How is the OP supposed to know that the 'reference' answer is suitable?

Comment: I've closevoted both of these posts as a duplicate of the canonical question. You're saying you're not sure if he was right to do so or not: what are your objections against it?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I don't have objection in that, my question is not why he closed that question, my question is a bit different that "So we all know there are many questions already and many question is being posted daily which only related to NullPointerException so should we close them as duplicate of this What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?"

Comment: Here's an answer with fundamentally the SAME content, perhaps even better.  It has 283 up votes and has protected status.  How come it's not a duplicate of the 'canonical' question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @GayotFow: I think you should look into the languages at hand. Android is really just a big library written in Java so they are not mutually exclusive. The question you linked is for the .NET framework which is used by, amongst others, C# and VB.NET; not Java. That question is in fact the canonical question about `NullReferenceExceptions` in .NET, while we're talking about `NullPointerExceptions` in Java.

Comment: Which language is being discussed in this sentence:  "You are trying to use a reference to an object, but you haven't initialized it (or it used to be initialized, but is now uninitialized)."

Comment: Just because two languages treat a particular concept the same, does not mean they will in the future as well. Aside from that, there is also the added confusion about some things that are possible in one language but not in the other. People who read about NRE/NPE for the first time will not appreciate seeing two languages interweaved, that only causes frustration. See also here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226583/should-a-question-about-the-design-of-c-be-closed-as-a-duplicate-of-a-java-ques/226584#226584

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes for this question. Looks like a valid question to me, +1.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When there is a question of the form:

> [giant block of code]
>
> I got a null pointer exception, how do I fix it

you can close it as a duplicate of that question.  Whenever its simply a matter of the user either not understanding what a null reference exception is, how to debug an application to find what references are null, etc. then that is all covered in the canonical question here.

In this specific case the duplicate closure seems appropriate.

That's not to say that every single question that ever possibly discusses a NPE is a duplicate of that question.  Some questions go beyond that, and the author of the question clearly already understands the information in that question, and their specific situation is more complex, for whatever reason.  Such questions would *not* be a duplicate.

Comment: Except that if you're getting a "NullReferenceException" then that's not Java and the above-referenced question for "NullPointerException" is not a "dupe".

Comment: `null reference exception` Did you mean: ***NullPointerException***

Comment: @HotLicks NRE is the .NET version of Java's NPE (just in case)

Answer (score 7):

I have recently been using my super powers to close-as-duplicate many `NullReferenceException` questions on Stack Overflow. This might be expected since I originated [the canonical `NullReferenceException`question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

What surprised me (and will surprise many who have gotten to know me on Stack Overflow) is the fact that there have been many such questions which I have *not* voted to close-as-duplicate. For instance,

- [WPF Object Reference not set to Instance of Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488380/wpf-object-reference-not-set-to-instance-of-object) was a case where the exception was thrown from inside of a third-party control, and not because the caller passed in a `null`, either.
- [c# code seems to get optimized in an invalid way such that an object value becomes null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379894/c-sharp-code-seems-to-get-optimized-in-an-invalid-way-such-that-an-object-value) was an actual compiler bug
- [Why is casting a dynamic of type object to object throwing a null reference exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931624/why-is-casting-a-dynamic-of-type-object-to-object-throwing-a-null-reference-exce) is a fairly esoteric case, and was also a compiler bug

So, yes, when closing questions like these, it's a good idea to actually understand the context.

Comment: It doesn't look that way to me. You're saying "c$ code seems to get optimized in an invalid way..." is the same as "Why is casting a dynamic"?

Comment: Thanks. Fixed. It's strange. First time I looked, they appeared different. Maybe I had a cached copy of the page.

Answer (score 5):

I have been struggling with this issue for some time. I primarily answer Android questions here and have seen far too many NPE questions closed as duplicate with a reference to this general Java NPE question: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

While I think the referenced question is quite useful as an explanation of what a NPE is and how to go about tracking it down, for many Android (and probably other framework) questions this is counter-productive.

Example: OP writes 3 lines of code and his app crashes with a NPE in a framework Thread with a stacktrace that contains absolutely none of his code.

Sending OP to the linked question isn't going to help. OP can guarantee that none of his variables are `null` (and they aren't) and since he has no idea how, when or why the framework is doing what it is doing he is completely at wits' end. To me, this is not at all useful or helpful nor is it in the spirit of the Stackoverflow community.

There are numerous cases in Android (and also other frameworks) where the framework will throw a NPE and none of the usual or recommended troubleshooting mechanisms can be used to find it. In order to fix these problems you need to have an understanding of how the framework works and what might be causing the problem. I don't think we can expect that beginner (or even intermediate) Android developers (of which, there are unfortunately, millions) will understand how the framework works behind the scenes, and it is unreasonable to expect them to research and understand that in the lmited time that their professor has given them to hand in the assignment (or their boss or client has given them to deliver the product).

I have been reopened such questions in the past, when it was clear that OP needed help understanding how the NPE was happening. I have also left suggestions for moderators not to close such questions as duplicates.

In general I have no problem closing questions as duplicates, if the duplicate question really offers an answer or solution to the OP's actual problem, but saying "all NPE's can be fixed like this ..." is just arrogant (IMHO).

I've listed a few examples of questions that have been closed as duplicate of the linked NPE question:

['void com.quickblox.chat.QBAbstractChat.sendMessage on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359002/void-com-quickblox-chat-qbabstractchat-sendmessage-on-a-null-object-reference?noredirect=1)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928321/nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-java-lang-string-java-la

[SinchService throwing NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277884/sinchservice-throwing-nullpointerexception)

[Admob crashes app with NullPointerException in DeviceMotionService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255863/admob-crashes-app-with-nullpointerexception-in-devicemotionservice)

Comment: There's two cases.  If the user says "I got an NPE while calling this function with these parameters (not because I called it directly on null)" or "I got an NPE because the return of this function was null, why was it null" then they deserve a more specific closure or an answer.  If they just have an NPE, closing it on the canonical i appropriate-  they can go back, do the research, and come back with a better question (or more likely fix the trivial bug they have).  But 99% of those questions are just someone coming with no effort or research, and should be sent back to work for themselves

Comment: I totally agree that the question is more like documentation related and yes, it is a good reference, but is not always useful is basically the same thing as if I example asked what is a deadlock and how do I fix them then every question that are related to a deadlock would be a possible duplicate and you could do that for all issues

Comment: People who come in asking questions are often accused of not doing minimal research or exerting minimal effort (and unfortunately it is often true), but sometimes it feels as if people voting to close are not making a minimal effort to thoroughly read the question and consider carefully whether it really is a duplicate or only so on the surface.

Comment: @G_H I agree. While I do consider myself somewhat arrogant, I do think it is better to actually read through the question and try to understand the problem, rather than automatically voting to close as "duplicate" just because OP posted a "NullPointerException".