# Are these questions considered duplicates or off topic?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I got a list of question that some way or another ask what is an index out of range exception:

- [C# Index Out Of Range Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842755/c-sharp-index-out-of-range-exception)
- [c# - Index out of range exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426525/c-sharp-index-out-of-range-exception)
- [Why do I get an Index out of Range exception when copying a Byte array into a Struct array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20918812/why-do-i-get-an-index-out-of-range-exception-when-copying-a-byte-array-into-a-st)
- [What is an "index out of range" exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812679/what-is-an-index-out-of-range-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Are these questions legitimate? Would they not be considered duplicates or off-topic?

Comment: They could be duplicates (I haven't read them). Why do you ask?

Comment: Do *you* think they are duplicates? Just because they haven't been marked as duplicates doesn't mean that they are not. We get a lot of questions! Sometimes things get missed. You can flag questions as duplicates if you think they are, just click the "flag" link underneath the tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes,** I would consider them to be duplicates.

The first three are not particularly good questions in the first place. They're just basically "debug my code for me"–style questions. Their only redeeming grace is that the askers actually did provide their code. That makes them poor questions, but nevertheless on topic.

Without close inspection (i.e., actually debugging the problem for them), I can't be sure if each one of them actually contains enough information to reproduce the problem, though. If not, they would be candidates for closing as "off topic", selecting the reason that states:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Fortunately, you don't have to worry about any of that in this particular case, since Robert Harvey has created [a canonical duplicate that addresses the *general* problem of "index out of range" exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812679/what-is-an-index-out-of-range-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). That's the last question you linked to.

<sup>(The exact same thing has been done for "debug my NullReferenceException" questions. See [this Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255062/nullpointerexception-question-on-stack-overflow) for more details.)</sup>

I think each of the first three questions should be closed as duplicates of that one. In fact, I went ahead and cast the close votes myself.

If ever you run across a question in the future that looks like a duplicate, please flag it for us! Use the "flag" link that appears just underneath the tags. We get a lot of questions on Stack Overflow, and sometimes duplicates get missed. The site is community moderated, so we appreciate your taking the time to help us clean it up!