# How to close unsolvable "crashes in main.m" for iOS/macOS?

Tags: discussion, canonical

A while ago I added [a tutorial link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) to the iOS tag wiki about how to fix application crashes in iOS. (It applies to macOS equally BTW, but that's not the point.)

Obviously, many question askers don't read that. There are still many new questions of the same format, e.g:

- [Abnormal main.m crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006769/abnormal-main-m-crash)
- [SIGABRT abort in main.m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976059/sigabrt-abort-in-main-m?rq=1)

What they have in common:

- They contain no "crash reason"
- All of them contain the same useless backtrace
- The OP obviously doesn't know the basics about how to fix crashes in iOS or macOS.

I would like to close them as duplicates and link to a canonical answer that explains how to create a useful crash report. (The real canonical answer is the ["My App Crashed, Now What?"-Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) IMHO.)

However, I cannot (and probably should not) answer each of these questions with "read this tutorial, because we cannot help you right now... here is the link: .."

I could vote to close them as *“Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.”* But this doesn't really help the OP.

What should be done with these kind of questions?

I think having a good, comprehensive, canonical answer for this kind of question and then marking all other questions as duplicates would be a good thing. What do you think?

Comment: If you had posted your tutorial as a self-answered Q&A, rather than on your blog, you could have closed them as duplicates of that canonical Q&A. This is still what I would recommend. Is that what you're asking, whether that would be a good idea?

Comment: @CodyGray: it‘s not my blog. The tutorial has been written by someone else. I would maybe do that if it where my tutorial.

Comment: @Michael You can still create a canonical Q&A and properly cite that external tutorial.

Comment: Do it. If there were [a canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319419/new-tag-suggestion-swift-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment325038_319445) for this, I could have [dupehammered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/159251) the first question you linked instead of just voting "Unclear".

Comment: When the heck we started to close questions as duplicated of questions that fundamentally don't answer the question?

Comment: I fear that the usual "crash in main.m" problem does not look like an "unclear what you are asking" or a "questions seeking debugging help must include the desired ..." problem. Many people know about Javas NullPointerException, even me who haven't done any Java programming for years, and who just barely knows the basics of the language. So it's hard to get them closed this way, because the question only seems obviously flawed to people who know a bit about iOS development.

Comment: The problem with marking it as duplicate though, is as @Braiam already pointed out, that the question cannot be anwered in a way that solves the OPs problem. But: telling the OP to look at a tutorial that teaches the basics is the only help he can get, but I fear that many OPs will consider that to be at least a bit rude, like in "I just asked a simple question. Why can't he just tell me the answer, and instead links to a tutorial?"

Comment: I just tried to answer [the first linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46006769/754705) in a canonical way...